# Linq group by distinct and iterate over it

Tags: linq

I want to list all categories of all published posts. But I would like to display categories just once. 
The `Post` class has a prop `Posts` and a constructor for the `Categories` prop. It's an string array instead of List and I would like to keep it that way.

```
public class Post
{
    public static List<Post> Posts = LoadPosts();
}

public Post()
{
    ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Categories = new string[0]; //array, no List<string>
}
```

This is my razor markup

```
<ul class="categories">
    @{var cl = Post.Posts.Where(p => p.IsPublished).Select(c => new List<string>(c.Categories));}
    @foreach (var cat in cl.Distinct())
    {
        <li>@cat</li>
    }
</ul>
```

This gives me as output

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

I have done something wrong in my Linq, but I am not experienced enough (or awake) to see my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) method:

```
Post.Posts
   .Where(p => p.IsPublished)  // IEnumerable<Post>
   .SelectMany(c => c.Categories) // IEnumerable<string>
   .Distinct()
```

It seems odd, but the real counterpart to the SQL `select` is not the `IEnumerable.Select` method, but the `IEnumerable.SelectMany`, because it can "flatten" the result of the selection, while `Select` makes a separate collection for each element, resulting in:

```
Post.Posts
  .Where(p => p.IsPublished)  // IEnumerable<Post>
  .Select(c => c.Categories) // IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>
  .Distinct() // does nothing, since all inner IEnumerable<string> 
              // objects are different
```

Comment: Thanks that did it! Now I have to wait 10 minutes to accept your answer.